# What should we ask the CMs to add to the "Cardano on Topic" page?

Tags: discussion

In answer to [How can we turn this flood of question that do not meet the site guidelines into a positive?](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-can-we-turn-this-flood-of-question-that-do-not-meet-the-site-guidelines-into)

Catija said:

> The CMs can also drop some guidance on the [Cardano On Topic](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page - y'all just need to formulate it for us.

Can we put it together here by answering, voting and consolidating?

Answer (score 3):

The Cardano stack exchange is for Developers, Stake pool operators, enthusiasts users and wonderers.

If you have a question **about …**

- Developing software that works with Cardano
- Stake pools and their operation
- How to use the Cardano ecosystem or accept Ada
- The Cardano ecosystem's network or protocols
- Open-source Cardano wallets or other Cardano software
- Technologies or events that are applicable and relevant to the Cardano network and users of the Ada currency

and it is **not about …**

- When will... be delivered/completed
- Will there be a....
- General programming techniques
- Investment advice and/or price of Ada and related tokens
- Politics or philosophy
- A site or software recommendation
- Any cryptocurrency or technology that is not applicable to the Cardano network and users of the Ada currency

then you’re probably in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: I started with something very similar to the on the Bitcoin stack exchange.  Looking for comments to help improve it.

Comment: I think the "you're probably in the right place" line should be placed under first paragraph.